# Java RegEx to find variable from getter and/or setter?

Tags: java, regex

I would like to know if I anyone knows a single java regular expression to "extract" the variable name from a java bean method name.

For example:

```
isABoolean         should return aBoolean
getMyInteger       should return myInteger 
setAnotherVariable should return anotherVariable
notAGetterMethod   should return nothing
isnotmymethod      should return nothing
```

I know I could use ((is)|(get)|(set)){1} to match the method prefixes, but I am having trouble with the lookahead for the following uppercase character and its replacement for the lowercase one.

Comment: Can you guarantee correct camel casing? If so, why not use a substring at the index of the first capital letter, and then drop that letter's case?

Comment: Java Regexp seem to be really restricted, so there is no version to lowercase a found match. Thus I would remove all the first lowercase Characters and then manually stringtolower the new first character. `String original = "blaABoolean"; String repl = original.replaceFirst("[a-z]+","");` and then some substring magic.

Answer (score 1):

You may want to use the class [**`java.beans.Introspector`**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/beans/Introspector.html) to obtain the names of the properties from the *target* class. See a full example in [List property names of a Bean](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Development-Class/ListpropertynamesofaBean.htm).

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a lookahead in most cases when you use regex, because regex engines store every matching group. So this `\s(is|get|set)(.*)(\(\))\s` should match the name of any getter/setter function, after it was matched you simply need to access the second matching group. How this is done depends on the context.

If you really need the lookahead and lookbehind the regex matching only the variable name would be `(?<=((\s)(is|get|set)))(.*)(?=((\(\))(\s)))`

Answer (score 0):

Short answer is: No, there is no single Java regular expression to extract property names from bean method names, because it involves "post-processing" of the name match.

There are standard ways to determine property names of a bean (see Paul Vargas' answer: `java.beans.Introspector`, or http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-beanutils/) and they should be used.

According to chapter *8.8 Capitalization of inferred names* in the [JavaBeans(TM) Specification 1.01 Final Release](http://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/jcp/7224-javabeans-1.01-fr-spec-oth-JSpec/) there are special cases:

1. getSomeProperty => property name is 'someProperty'
2. getX => property name is 'x'
3. getURL => property name stays 'URL' (not 'uRL' or 'url')

This means e.g. that `isABoolean` should result in `ABoolean` instead of `aBoolean`, if you stick to the specification.